# Update ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I received cursor from Database and set andapter to ListView. Then I insert new row  to Database, but my ListView didn't update.

```html
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(GEN_URI, null, null, null, null);

String[] from = { DB.column_name };
int[] to = { R.id.textViewItem };

myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.shop_list_item, c, from, to, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER );
 
ShopList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

ContentValues newC = new ContentValues();
newC.put(DB.column_name, "Селёдочка");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(SHOP_LIST_URI, newC);
getContentResolver().query(GEN_URI, null, null, null, null);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If I set flag SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER - ListView don't update.
If I set flag SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY- ListView update.

What do?

Comment: Have you tried myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after updating data?

Comment: see CursorAdapter#onContentChanged, this method is called when using FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER flag, you can override that method in your CursorAdapter and do whatever you want, base implementation is here: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must notify the adapter that data has changed and tell it to refresh.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When using the flag autorequery, the cursor automatically requeris and hence, your listview is getting updated, But as far as I know, this FLAG_AUTO_REQUEY is now deprecated.

**UPDATE**

After some googling, I found out that notifyDataSetChanged has nothing to do with SimpleCursorAdapters.

So the workaround is requers(). But as I stated it is deprecated and the new method is by changing the Cursor.

```
adapter.changeCursor(cursor) and send it to your adapter.
```

Here is the google's official documentation about requery().

Comment: I added myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
But ListView still not been updated

Comment: @СтасПишевский notifyDataSetChanged has nothing to do with your case

Comment: Hirak Chhatbar, I did so:
Cursor newC = getContentResolver().query(GEN_URI, null, null, null, null);
myAdapter.changeCursor(newC );

Answer (score 2):

You can tryed myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();